# Rails function returns HTML-name characters instead of the actual character

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a function:

```
def div
"<div>blah</div>"
end
```

and in the view:

```
<%= div %>
```

but in the resulting page source:

```
&lt;div&gt;blah&lt;/div&gt;
```

instead of the actual string text.

However, the console displays the correct tags.

```
<% logger.info(div) %>
```

Outputs in the console:

```
<div>blah</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead.

```
<%= raw div %>
```

Rails 3 escapes everything coming from the server in views, you can use `raw` if you're sure you trust the data.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you want to be able to use

```
<%= div %>
```

in your view, you can define your function like this and it will work too:

```
def div
  "<div>blah</div>".html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Rails 2 text was raw by default, now in Rails 3 they make vice versa